# Leaflet Draw on Mobile - creating a marker

Tags: leaflet, web-mapping, mobile

So I made a simple leaflet map that has the Leaflet Draw plugin.  I am only allowing users to add a marker. Leaflet is supposed to be mobile friendly, but when I open my website in a smartphone (Galaxy s5 chrome browser app), I cannot touch to create a marker on draw:created.  Is there a specific procedure necessary to adapt the draw plugin for mobile touch events?

I looked at https://github.com/tablackmore/Leaflet.draw/tree/touch and tried to redirect my page to a new index which uses the "touch" draw plugin instead of the original plugin but still nothing is "drawing".  This could be because it is not directing.  I am using this script reference http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/mobile-redirect.  I want to redirect my site to mobile.html rather than index.html.  Regardless of whether my redirect works or not, shouldn't the basic draw plugin work on mobile?

Does anyone have a working example of a leaflet map on a mobile device with drawing capabilities?

For what it's worth here is my project- but it is a novice example and quite messy: http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~melrose/DVA/index.html

PS. This map shows test data only- no real data is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The draw plugin currently has no touch support. This is a much-asked-for feature, but it's not currently available.

You can use the Leaflet plugin "[Simple Marker](https://github.com/jdomingu/Leaflet.SimpleMarkers)" which works perfectly fine with a mobile device. (only tested on iOS devices though).
This plugin is only limited to drawing new points/markers. No polygon or line support, but your original question didn't specify those unsupported features.